# Correctness of the sentence

Tags: grammar, usage

I want to say about shades of a color: *«Yellow shades of honey and lemon are good»*. Is it semantically correct and clear? Should I put articles somewhere in the sentense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is fine.

It talks about honey and lemon in general terms rather than about any particular honey or lemon.

If you were talking about a particular pot of honey and a particular lemon or lemons, you would say:

**Yellow shades of the honey and the lemon/s are good.**

More specifically, using **the** yellow shades draws attention to the shades you are referring to.

While your sentence is grammatically correct, it's not clear what you mean by **good**.

It might simply signify your approval, or it might be a comment that you make to an artist. This doesn't really matter unless you wish to put your sentence in context.

PS. Note the spelling of **sentence**.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is clear and grammatically correct. It declares an opinion of the writer that the "Yellow shades..." are "...good."; presumably other sentences put a context onto this to explain what is meant by that, since by itself it doesn't communicate that much to the reader. Are they good for aesthetics? Are they indicators of good, put there by someone to indicate some kind of quality? Are they in an environment with other shades which they match or complement?